# Windows phone - Avoid scrolling of Web browser control placed inside scroll viewer

Tags: scroll, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control, windows-phone, scrollviewer

I have to show a **web browser inside a scroll viewer** in windows phone application, with these requirements :

1. Web browser **height** should be adjusted **based on its content**.
2. Web browser **scrolling** should be **disabled**, ( when user scrolls within web browser, scrolling of scroll viewer should take place )
3. Web browser **can do pinch-zoom and navigate to links** inside its content.

   How can I implement that? Any links or samples is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using code like this. Attach events to the Border element in the Browser control tree (I'm using Linq to Visual Tree - http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/).

```
        Browser.Loaded += 
            (s,e)=>
                {
                    var border = Browser.Descendants<Border>().Last() as Border;

                    if (border != null)
                    {
                        border.ManipulationDelta += BorderManipulationDelta;
                        border.ManipulationCompleted += BorderManipulationCompleted;
                        border.DoubleTap += BorderDoubleTap;
                    }
                };
```

Further more the implementation I'm using is to prevent pinch and zoom, something you want to have working. Though this should help you in the right direction.

```
private void BorderDoubleTap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}

private void BorderManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    // suppress zoom
    if (Math.Abs(e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X) > 0.0||
        Math.Abs(e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.Y) > 0.0)
        e.Handled = true;
}

private void BorderManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // suppress zoom
    if (Math.Abs(e.FinalVelocities.ExpansionVelocity.X) > 0.0 ||
        Math.Abs(e.FinalVelocities.ExpansionVelocity.Y) > 0.0)
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. Yes your answer showed right direction. As             private void Border_ManipulationDelta(object sender,                                          System.Windows.Input.ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)        {                                                                                e.Complete();
            _browser.IsHitTestVisible = false;           
}

Comment: Is BorderDoubleTap getting fired?

Answer (score 1):

On Mark's direction, I used

```
private void Border_ManipulationDelta(object sender,
                                              System.Windows.Input.ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
        {

            e.Complete();
            _browser.IsHitTestVisible = false;

        }
```